# How to locate td class in html code using python?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, data-extraction

I have a class in my html code. I need to locate td class "Currentlocation" using python.

CODE :

```
<td class="CURRENTLOCATION"><img align="MIDDLE" src="..\Images\FolderOpen.bmp"/> Metrics</td>
```

Below are the codes I tried.

First attempt:

```
My_result = page_soup.find_element_by_class_name('CURRENTLOCATION')
```

Getting "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable" error. Second attempt:

```
My_result = page_soup.find(‘td’, attrs={‘class’: ‘CURRENTLOCATION’})
```

Getting "invalid character in identifier" error.

Can anyone please help me locate a class in html code using python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
sdata = '<td class="CURRENTLOCATION"><img align="MIDDLE" src="..\Images\FolderOpen.bmp"/> Metrics</td>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(sdata, 'lxml')
mytds = soup.findAll("td", {"class": "CURRENTLOCATION"})
for td in mytds: 
    print(td)
```

Comment: I have piece of html code as a list in "soup1".  Any idea how to pass it as lxml?       
  I tried "soup1 = soup(myresult1, 'lxml')" but it throws me error. Can you help me with this?

Comment: How a html code is in list? ...It should be string right?

Comment: [<tr valign="TOP"><td>Location:</td><td>Chennai </td></tr>,
 <tr valign="TOP"><td>Description:</td><td>Place of stay</td></tr>] This is the sample of the output I have. Isn't it list?

Comment: @Jansirani covert all your list data into string and pass to `BeautifulSoup`  or else pass single list element to `BeautifulSoup` ,loop over list elements

Comment: Thank you, i converted the result set into string and then passed it into beautiful soup as lxml.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in BeautifulSoup for this.
You can get all the desired tags and specify the attributes which you are lookin for in find_all function. It returns the list of all the elements which fulfill the criteria

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
text = '<td class="CURRENTLOCATION"><img align="MIDDLE" src="..\Images\FolderOpen.bmp"/> Metrics</td>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')
output_list = soup.find_all('td',{"class": "CURRENTLOCATION"}) # I am looking for all the td tags whose class atrribute is set to CURRENTLOCATION
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, the second example, and the problem are the quotation marks you use. To me they are apostrophes (‘, unicode code point \u2019), while the python interpreter requires single (') or double (") quotation marks.

Changing them I can find the tag:

```
>>> bs.find('td', attrs={'class': 'CURRENTLOCATION'})
<td class="CURRENTLOCATION"><img align="MIDDLE" src="..\Images\FolderOpen.bmp"/> Metrics</td>
```

About your first example. I do not know where you find a reference to the method `find_element_by_class_name` but it seems to not be implemented by the BeautifulSoup class. The class instead implements the `__getattr__` method that is a special one that is invoked anytime you try to access a non existing attribute. Here an excerpt of the method:

```
def __getattr__(self, tag):
    #print "Getattr %s.%s" % (self.__class__, tag)
    if len(tag) > 3 and tag.endswith('Tag'):
        #
    # We special case contents to avoid recursion.
    elif not tag.startswith("__") and not tag == "contents":
        return self.find(tag)
```

When you try to access the attribute `find_element_by_class_name`, you are actually looking for a tag with the same name.